# TV show - prisoners get lethal injection but end up elsewhere afterwards

Tags: story-identification, tv, parallel-universe

All I remember is in the show prisoners were given a lethal injection, then find themselves in a strange world, hell or an alien planet. Possibly part of an experiment?

Further detail: It was on tv in the 90's. Death row prisoners were injected, but the injection transported them to an hellish world instead as if part of a conspiracy known only to the jail.

Comment: When did you watch it? Was it in English? Do you remember anything about main characters - if they were male/female/giant creatures? Was it in color? Anything you remember, no matter how small may help us help you.

Comment: The question is half searching for "Alcatraz" as an answer. But if your description of the plot point is accurate, then I'm wrong.

Comment: Probably not it, but just in case, the SyFy adaptation of Philip José Farmer's [Riverworld](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1419950/)

Comment: Did it have D.B. Sweeney in it, released around 2000-2002 time frame? Were they stuck in a computer program ran by a man named Santiago?

Comment: It sounds like the Outer Limits episode "The Sentence" in which an inventor inadvertently condemns himself to a lengthy term in a virtual prison, a hellish penal environment that he himself created.

Answer (score 2):

I think the show that you are thinking of is "[The Burning Zone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0533939/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)" and the episode name is "Lethal Injection". Good luck finding it as I never was able to. It was on the CW when it was UPN.

Comment: The summary at IMDB, http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0533939/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl, doesn't seem to match.